# Postgresql JSONB object column to Array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am working with an existing table, where the column is of type JSONB. The data looks like this:

```
{ key1: {...}, key2: {...}}
```

I would like to migrate all the existing data in this DB so that this JSONB data looks like this instead:

```
[{ key1: {...}, key2: {...}}]
```

I want the existing object to be wrapped in an array.

I think I might be able to use **jsonb_build_array**, but I'm not completely sure.

Has anyone had to do this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, jsonb_build_array() is the right approach:

```
update the_table
   set the_column = jsonb_build_array(the_column);
```

Comment: Great! Can this be easily reverted? I didn't see a way to undo this update, if needed.

Comment: Use a transaction and do a rollback if needed